# Datepicker inside search box

Tags: sapui5

I want to put datepicker (sap.m.DatePicker) inside search box, so that I can choose date if I want to search for any specific date. Currently, I am using this code:

```
<SearchField id="searchField4" search="onSearch2" width="auto"><DatePicker id="DP1" placeholder="Enter Date ..." change="handleChange"/></SearchField>
```

However, it does not work. Any idea whats wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that the sap.m.SearchField control does not support DatePicker in it's aggregation.

SearchField has only one aggregation **suggestionItems** which is also the default one. This aggregation only supports controls of the type sap.m.SuggestionItem. So a sap.m.DatePicker is an invalid control for it.

Reference: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SearchField.html
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SearchField/aggregations

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. It falls on the line 12 of UIComponent.js:

[image]

It throws error:

```
"Element sap.m.DatePicker#__xmlview2--DP1" is not valid for aggregation "suggestionItems" of Element sap.m.SearchField#__xmlview2--searchField4
```